I am trying to create a script that allows me to use an excel document to mass update meta data in the sitecore content hub
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'long'  UpdateMetaData  71  Active
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'long'  UpdateMetaData      110 Active
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'long'  UpdateMetaData  118 Active
Error   CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from '' to 'Stylelabs.M.Framework.Essentials.LoadConfigurations.IEntityLoadConfiguration'    UpdateMetaData      71  Active
Error   CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from '' to 'Stylelabs.M.Framework.Essentials.LoadConfigurations.IEntityLoadConfiguration'    UpdateMetaData      110 Active
Error   CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from '' to 'Stylelabs.M.Framework.Essentials.LoadConfigurations.IEntityLoadConfiguration'   UpdateMetaData      118 Active
Error   CS1501  No overload for method 'SaveAsync' takes 3 arguments    UpdateMetaData  104 Active
Warning CS8618  Non-nullable field 'MClient' must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring the field as nullable.  UpdateMetaData      14  Active
using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using OfficeOpenXml; // EPPlus
    using Stylelabs.M.Sdk.WebClient;
    using Stylelabs.M.Sdk.WebClient.Authentication;
    
    namespace Stylelabs.M.WebSdk.Examples
    {
        public class Program
        {
            // Make MClient a class-level variable for accessibility
            private static IWebMClient MClient;
    
            static async Task Main(string[] args)
            {
                Uri endpoint = new Uri("URL);
                OAuthPasswordGrant oauth = new OAuthPasswordGrant
                {
                    ClientId = "ID",
                    ClientSecret = "Secret",
                    UserName = "username",
                    Password = "password"
                };
    
                // Declare and instantiate the MClient here to be accessible
                MClient = MClientFactory.CreateMClient(endpoint, oauth);
    
                try
                {
                    // Call TestConnectionAsync
                    await MClient.TestConnectionAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine("Connection to Sitecore Content Hub successful!");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
                    return; // Exit if connection fails
                }
    
                // Path to the Excel file (use verbatim string literal)
                string excelFilePath = File Path";
                if (!File.Exists(excelFilePath))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Excel file not found: {excelFilePath}");
                    return;
                }
    
                // Read the Excel file and process rows
                using (var package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(excelFilePath)))
                {
                    var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0]; // First sheet in the Excel file
                    int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.Rows;
    
                    for (int row = 2; row <= rowCount; row++) // Start from row 2 to skip headers
                    {
                        string fileName = worksheet.Cells[row, 1].Text;
                        string brands = worksheet.Cells[row, 2].Text;
                        string productFamilies = worksheet.Cells[row, 3].Text;
                        string products = worksheet.Cells[row, 4].Text;
                        string title = worksheet.Cells[row, 5].Text;
    
                        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileName))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("File name is missing, skipping row.");
                            continue; // Skip empty rows
                        }
    
                        // Attempt querying the asset
                        var queryResult = await MClient.Entities.GetAsync("M.Asset", new { filterQuery = $"FileName eq '{fileName}' or Title eq '{title}'" });
    
                        if (queryResult?.Results?.Any() == true)
                        {
                            // Update existing asset
                            var assetId = queryResult.Results.First().Id; // No need to call ToString() for conversion
                            await UpdateAssetMetadata(MClient, assetId, brands, productFamilies, products, title);
                            Console.WriteLine($"Updated asset: {fileName}");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Report missing asset
                            Console.WriteLine($"Missing asset: {fileName}");
                        }
                    }
                }
    
                Console.WriteLine("Processing complete. Press any key to exit...");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }  // Closing brace for Main method
    
            private static async Task UpdateAssetMetadata(IWebMClient client, long assetId, string brands, string productFamilies, string products, string title)
            {
                // Build the asset metadata
                var assetMetadata = new
                {
                    Title = title,
                    Brands = new[] { new { target = await GetOrCreateRelation(client, "Brands", brands) } },
                    ProductFamilies = new[] { new { target = await GetOrCreateRelation(client, "Product Families", productFamilies) } },
                    Products = new[] { new { target = await GetOrCreateRelation(client, "Products", products) } }
                };
    
                // Update the asset metadata
                await MClient.Entities.SaveAsync("M.Asset", assetId, assetMetadata);  // For updating asset metadata
            }
    
            private static async Task<string> GetOrCreateRelation(IWebMClient client, string relationType, string value)
            {
                // Check if the relation exists
                var existingRelations = await MClient.Entities.GetAsync(relationType, new { filterQuery = $"Name eq '{value}'" });
    
                if (existingRelations?.Results?.Any() == true)
                {
                    return existingRelations.Results.First().Id; // Return existing relation ID
                }
    
                // For creating new asset relations
                var newRelation = await MClient.Entities.GetAsync("M.Asset", new { Name = value });
                return newRelation.Id;
            }
        } // Closing brace for Program class
    }


Can you please confirm Brands, ProductFamilies and Products are already stored in the content hub and you are trying to link them to asset using the ids stored in the excel sheet. In case you can elablorate a little on the entities you have in Content Hub and how you are looking to associate them with the asset, would be helpful to share the solution for this.

Confirmed they are stored in the content hub. I am basically just trying to add titles to the assets - but not by the ID by the file name.

Can you please try the following code instead of UpdateAsync:
var assestEntity = await ContentHubClient.GetEntityById(webMClient, assestId);
assestEntity.SetPropertyValue(propertyName, objectValue);
await webMClient.Entities.SaveAsync(assestEntity); 

and for CreateAsync:
var newRelation = await client.EntityFactory.CreateAsync("M.Asset", CultureLoadOption.Default).ConfigureAwait(false);

See the documentation for more details:

Entities client
Guide to Utilizing the Web Client SDK - Part 1
Guide to Utilizing the Web Client SDK - Part 2


I updated my script and got some new errors - then I updated it again and got a whole bunch of new errors haha - I updated my script above with the new errors. I am also willing to use any other solutions if you have done this before. I am just trying to find a way to have a script read an excel document with a file name and a title and have the script read the file and update the asset title by looking for it by the file name and if there  is a file name in the excel doc that isn't content hub have it tell me it's missing.
